# Crystal Reports - Adding a parameter to a 'Command' query(help)

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, command, report

I 'm trying to add a parameter to the SQL commands in Crystal Report through the VB6 in the first part and simple to do and could send the parameters , now the second party does not know how to send this information to the crystal accepted SQL .

PART 1:

```
ID IN ('1286460',
                 '1281450',
                 '1359340',
                 '1376330',
                 '1355510',
                 '1352860')
```

**PART 2:

```
ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN ID= 1286460 THEN 0
            WHEN ID= 1281450 THEN 1
            WHEN ID= 1359340 THEN 2
            WHEN ID= 1376330 THEN 3
            WHEN ID= 1355510 THEN 4
            WHEN ID= 1352860 THEN 5
         END
```

**

PART 1: ITS WORK

```
( {V_EMP.ID} = "1286460" OR  {V_EMP.ID} = "1281450" OR  {V_EMP.ID} = "1359340" OR  {V_EMP.ID} = "1376330" OR  {V_EMP.ID} = "1355510" OR  {V_EMP.ID} = "1352860")
```

PART 2: 
**this part do not know how to do!**

Comment: can you post your sql query

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Add query
- Click the `Create...` button
- Create a string parameter named `Employee IDs`; select 'allow multiple values'
- Add to `WHERE` clause: `WHERE ... AND V_EMP.ID IN {? Employee IDs}`

Comment: Yes this part is done , the problem when sending the parameter of Part 2 , do not know how I will format it for the crystal accept.
I am sending the parameter through the VB6 . I have already sent the parameter of part 1 which is the basic of the crystal now the part 2 I am not able to build it .

Answer (score 0):

Yes this part is done , the problem when sending the parameter of Part 2 , do not know how I will format it for the crystal accept.
I am sending the parameter through the VB6 . I have already sent the parameter of part 1 which is the basic of the crystal now the part 2 I am not able to build it .

Comment: You need to use sub reports